# The best way to plot a math function with multiple parameters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scientific-computing

I'm (theoretical) physics student and I'm really new to this programming stuff. I'm trying to plot the radial Schrodinger wave function of a 2d quantum system in Python but I'm having lots of troubles

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#beta parameter definition
def beta(m, flux, gama):
    flux = np.linspace(0,1.0)
    return np.sqrt((m-flux)**2+gama**4)

#radial wave function definition
beta = beta(0.067*9.1E-31, 0.5, 1.5)
R=5.0E-9
r=np.linspace(0, 0.6)
ro = r/R
def radial (n,gama,beta, ro, R,r):
    return (1/R)*np.sqrt((ss.gamma(n+1)/2**beta*ss.gamma(n+beta+1)))*(gama*ro)**beta*np.exp(-(gama*ro)**2/4)*ss.eval_genlaguerre(n,beta,((gama*ro)**2/2))

sol = radial(0, 1.5, beta, ro, R,r)
plt.plot(ro, sol, 'b-')
plt.xlabel('r/R')
plt.ylabel('R(r)')
plt.title('Solução radial em fução da coordenada radial')
plt.legend("gamma=1,5")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I would like to ask: what's the best way to pass multiple parameters to a math function?
Even with multiple parameters and special functions I get just an straight line on the plot.
Thanks for any tips or help.

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi, @juanpa.arrivillaga, I managed to fix the error. I changed all the np.arrange for np.linspace. At least it gave me the plot, but completely wrong

Comment: @DanielLima did you ever get this to work? would you share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inputting a non boolean into a boolean argument in the genlaguerre function
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.genlaguerre.html

```
def genlaguerre(n: int,
                alpha: float,
                monic: Optional[bool] = False) -> orthopoly1d)
```

you are inputting:

```
ss.genlaguerre(n=n,
               alpha=beta,
               monic=((gama*ro)**2/2)  #  <--- this is your issue
               )
```

Comment: Hi, @ak_slick, I changed genlaguerre for eval_genlaguerre and I got it right, thanks

Comment: @Daniel Lima Excellent. Please select an answer. In this case since they are the same please select mine since it was posted first.

Comment: But I still have one more question: what is the proper way to declare a large number of parameters wich are related with on another and that will have many values assigned to them?

Comment: I would need an example and would recommend asking another question. There are several ways to do it but I think a data frame would most likely be the way to go for ease. Ask another question with example data and output. Send me a message once you do and I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The function `ss.genlaguerre` takes a bool as the third argument, not an array.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.genlaguerre.html#scipy.special.genlaguerre

Comment: I changed ss.laguerre for ss.eval_languerre. Thanks